# Inaccurate output when trying to calculate distance between two points in R using OSM data and the geosphere distm() function

Tags: r, google-maps, openstreetmap, geosphere

I am trying to calculate the shortest distance between a point of interest and the nearest tram station, the coordinates are in latitude and longitude (degrees) as a POINT type object. To do this I create an empty vector (distance) which I add to my dataframe containing the spatial point data and then fill the distance column using a for-loop which calculates the distance between my previously defined point of interest and all the coordinates in the dataframe using the `distm()` function with the distGeo function. Then I use the `min()` function on the distance column to find the shortest distance.

The problem I am having is not that the code is not doing what I want it to do, but that when I use the right click measure distance function in Google Maps, their distance is up to 30% shorter than the one my code outputs. All the coordinates are in the right order, and when I type them into Google Maps, the correct points show up, but the calculated distance is still wrong.

For example, the POI is `49.49443499565662`, `8.459728292754358` and the nearest tram station is at `49.49353`, `8.461322`. My code calculates a distance of 202.39m and Google Maps calculates a distance of `152.66m`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Keep in mind that I am not very experienced with R or OpenStreetMap.

Here's my code:

```r
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(geosphere)

#define city
city = "Mannheim"

#define coordinates of interest point
p68 = c(49.49443499565662, 8.459728292754358)

#query for tram routes in Mannheim
mannheim_tram_routes <- getbb(city) %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = 'route', value = 'tram')

#translating the query into sp format
mtr <- osmdata_sf(mannheim_tram_routes)

#creating vector
distances=c(1:length(mtr$osm_points$osm_id))
#creating a dataframe from the sp format 
mtrdf <- data.frame(mtr$osm_points)
#adding the distance vector to the dataframe
mtrdf$distances = distances 
#selecting only the relevant columns for the dataframe
mtrdf <- mtrdf %>% 
  select(osm_id,name,distances,geometry)
#deleting all rows with with no names (only the stations are left from the tram route data)
mtrdf2 <- na.omit(mtrdf)

#filling the distance column with a for-loop using distm()
for(i in 1:length(mtrdf2$distances)){
  mtrdf2$distances[i] =distm(p68, c(mtrdf2$geometry[[i]][2],mtrdf2$geometry[[i]][1]),fun =distGeo)
}
#checking for the smallest distance 
min(mtrdf2$distances)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the arguments matters, and `geosphere::` functions prefer longitude first. I'm inferring that your tram is 49.49353 north latitude, 8.461322 east longitude.

If I (incorrectly) calculate it with latitude first, I get your 202 results:

```r
geosphere::distGeo(c(49.49443499565662, 8.459728292754358), c(49.49353, 8.461322))
# [1] 202.4823
```

But if I put longitude first instead, I get closer to Google's results:

```r
geosphere::distGeo(c(8.459728292754358, 49.49443499565662), c(8.461322, 49.49353))
# [1] 153.1708
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and comprehensive answer! I thought that 49.49366066246722, 8.460254480742616 was the correct order, because when you right click in google maps, that is the order in which you can copy the coordinates.

Comment: Apparently Google didn't first check with Robert J. Hijmans and company for the proper order to display in Maps ;-)